# Probability Function for Transistors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A box of 5 transistors is known to contain 3 that are defective. The transistors
are to be tested, one at a time, until the defective ones are identified. Denote by N1 the
number of tests made until the first defective is spotted and by N2 the number of additional
tests until the second defective is spotted. Specify the values N1 and N2 can take. Find the
joint probability mass function of N1 and N2.

My approach was to find the probability of the first defective transistor for the first part. I am also sure that `N1 + N2 <= 5`, so the options for N1 can only be 1,2,3,4 but for N2 the options can be 1,...,5-N1. The problem is I am unable to understand how will I use this information to find the probability for first defective transistor and then for second transistor given that first is defective.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention my approach. Let me edit. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @angryavian, My approach was to find the probability of the first defective transistor for the first part. I am also sure that `N1 + N2 <= 5`, so the options for N1 can only be 1,2,3,4 but for N2 the options can be 1,...,5-N1. The problem is I am unable to understand how will I use this information to find the probability for first defective transistor and then for second transistor given that first is defective.

Comment: Remember that there are three defective transistors. You can't have $N_1 + N_2 = 5$, because then the third one has disappeared.

Comment: @Arthur, but I don't care what happens to the third transistor as it does not change my answer since the question doesn't say anything about the third transistor.

Comment: @Anenim_12 Whether you personally care about or is asked about the third transistor doesn't change the fact that something like $N_1 = 3, N_2 = 2$ (i.e. finding your first faulty transistor on the third test, and then take two more tests to find your second one) is entirely impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the ways you can order two good (G) and three defective (D) transistors, e.g. $GGDDD$ or $GDDGD$. There are $10$ orderings. For each ordering, write down what $N_1$ and $N_2$ are. Then the joint mass function, say, $f(1,1)$ is the number of orderings where $N_1=1$ and $N_2=1$, divided by $10$. (I think in this case the function will either be $1/10$ or $0$ at each point, you need to figure out the details.)

Comment: I see, but I am unable to comprehend what you meant by N1 = 1 and N2 = 1. Both of them cannot be the same at the same time !!

Comment: @Anenim_12 Your problem statement says "Denote [...] by N2 the number of **additional** tests until the second defective is spotted." Not "the total number tests until the second defective is spotted." Thus $N_1 = 1, N_2 = 1$ means that the first transistor you tested was faulty, and then the first one you tested after that was also faulty.